# Comparing two numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, numpy-slicing

Initializing the empty numpy array

```
y=np.empty((2,2),dtype=np.matrix)
b=np.empty((2,2),dtype=np.matrix)
```

Assigning values to above arrays

```
b[0][0]=np.mat([
[67,57],
[19,56]])

b[0][1]=np.mat([
[7,58],
[9,46]])  

b[1][0]=np.mat([
[77,47],
[34,34]])

b[1][1]=np.mat([
[2,66],
[78,45]])

y[0][0]=np.mat([
[67,57],
[19,56]])

y[0][1]=np.mat([
[7,58],
[9,46]]) 

 y[1][0]=np.mat([
[77,47],
[34,34]])

y[1][1]=np.mat([
[2,66],
[78,45]])
```

Printing the array

```
print(y)
print(b)
```

The y and b arrays are equal and it should print True but instead it is printing False

```
print(np.array_equal(y,b))
print(y==b)
```

Comment: You're using the deprecated/ *no longer recommended* *matrix* api. *y, b* are of dtype `object`, basically checking element-wise reference equality with `y==b`, which is `False`.

Comment: Y,b is of type np.ndarray. While elements of y,b are of matrix type .You can check it yourself . Can you suggest other way to compare these two arrays

Comment: Did you check `b.dtype, y.dtype`? I can suggest using ctyped `np.array`, don't use `object` arrays or `np.matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as Michael Szczesny mentioned, `np.mat` is deprecated and you should avoid it. Object arrays are also kinda iffy but can serve a purpose sometimes. Although to answer the actual question:

To check for equality between these arrays of arrays you need to check that the inner arrays are equal and then go from there. To do this you can trick numpy into applying `np.array_equal` element wise and then check with `np.all`

```
import numpy as np
deep_equal = np.vectorize(np.array_equal)
def inner_array_equal(a,b): return np.all(deep_equal(a,b))


a = np.empty(2,dtype=object)
b = np.empty(2,dtype=object)

a[0] = np.array([1,2])
a[1] = np.array([3,4])

b[0] = np.array([1,2])
b[1] = np.array([3,4])

print(a,b)

print(inner_array_equal(a,b))
```

Notice that I switched your code to be explicit object arrays (although `dtype=np.matrix` will do the same thing) and filled them with `np.array` instead.